# How to solve a nonlinear recursion relation?

Tags: recursion

Given the following recursion relation
\begin{equation}
E^{(n)}=(E^{(n-1)}-\alpha_1)\,e^{-\alpha_2\,(\alpha_3E^{(n-1)}+b)}
\end{equation}

where $\alpha_i$'s and $b$ are some constants.

I am trying to find $E^{(n)}$ as a function of $E^{(1)}$, but I am not sure if there is a clear way to do so, what do you guys think?

Comment: Maybe try with some trivial values of the constants and see if you can solve that. E.g., an analytical form for the recurrence $E_n=E_{n-1}\exp(-E_{n-1})$. Though this alone seems quite hard, which suggests that you should probably content yourself with giving sufficient conditions for non-blowup and numerical computation.

Comment: sure, one can consider those constant such that reduce the main relation to the one you wrote but as you pointed out still not easy!

Comment: That's exactly my point. Maybe it is not worth your while looking for an *analytical* solution. Perhaps its best to characterize non-blowup and compute the recurrence *numerically*.